# Multiboot not recognizing windows 7 as installed

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I'm trying to install ubuntu onto an old laptop as a second os. I've successfully done this before but yesterday the drive got corrupted and I lost everything. I'm in the process of reinstalling the oses I had installed but when I go to install ubuntu, it says there are no recognized install operating systems. i have almost 2/3 of the disk as unallocated space with windows 7 on a 75G partition. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You did not boot the installer into UEFI mode. I had no luck doing so, but I can change the bios. Give me the brand of laptop you have if you wan't to do so.

If you do not wan't to do so, do the following:

In the installation option menu, click "Something Else"                                                                                 Once opened, create a new ext4 partition in the unallocated space and mount it at /

It should look something like this
[image]
Continue with the installation, and voila!

Comment: i have a dell XPS-M1330 i know how to change the bios myself so i will do that.